# Nativescript Code Behind - Add GridLayout to ScrollView Dynamically

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I am creating a dynamic GridLayout in Nativescript following the example on there page:

https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/layouts/layout-containers

It allows my to make a GridLayout using javascript, as I need it to be dynamic.

However, I want to put this layout in a ScrollView.

I believe I'm meant to do something like this

```
const grid = new GridLayout();
const scroll = new ScrollView();  
grid.addChild();

...

scroll.addView(grid);
```

I constantly get an error saying "addView" is not a function.

Is this the correct method? What 'require("");' do I need for the ScrollView?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import from
`import { ScrollView } from 'ui/scroll-view';`

and it's not addView, available public method is [_addView](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_scroll_view_.scrollview#_addview)

Comment: Thanks Narendra, so can I only do this in angular? The system is written in javascript, I know how to call import in JS, but will is still be _addView?

Comment: You can use require e.g. const scroll = require('../../ui/scroll-view'); and yes method name still will be _addView

Comment: So I did: const ScrollView = require("tns-core../ui/scroll-view"); I then did 'const scroll = new ScrollView' - I got error (ScrollView is not a function), i then tried ScrollView._addView(grid) and it said (ScrollView._addView is not a function)

Comment: should be var scroll = new ScrollView(); Is there any specific reason you want to add scrollview from code, you can have it in yout html and access it var scrollView = page.getViewById('SCROLL_VIEW_ID')

Comment: The way I'm calling the pages in the project require to use code. I finally got the scrollview working with no errors, however I get nothing displayed. Once I go scroll._addView(grid) i did page.content = scroll; And its just blank?

Comment: check you contect in grid and make sure their height, width row and columns ids are correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181913/discussion-between-narendra-mongiya-and-thegoldend0nut).

Comment: I've continued this in chat @Narendra

Answer (score 1):

So just as reference for anyone else in the future.

The _addView() method wouldn't throw any errors, however I couldn't get the scene to actually load or show anything.

If there is a way to load the _addView() correctly then more than happy fo someone to add that comment.

The playground for that method is below:

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=LlsHLd

The way I got it working is by doing the following:

```
const scrollView = require("tns-core-modules/ui/scroll-view").Scroll-View;
var scrollV = new scrollView();

(Dynamically load a gridlayout)
grid.addChild()
....

scroll.content = grid;
page.content = scroll;
```

Thanks everyone for the help.