# Nativescript - Add ActionBar through Code

Tags: javascript, nativescript

Original Question:
*Just trying to find out if you can add an action bar through code in Nativescript JS
And if so, How would you go about it?*

New Question:
So the following code loads the actionbar dynamically:

```
var actionB = require("tns-core-modules/ui/action-bar).ActionBar;

var actB = new actionB();
actB.title = "Action Bar";
actB.id = "actionID"
```

page.content = actB;

Now I just need to know how would I load navigation item and action item for android and ios

Thanks

Comment: I haven't tried that personally but should be same in the way your were adding grid and scroll view in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52825771/nativescript-code-behind-add-gridlayout-to-scrollview-dynamically/52827574#52827574

Comment: Although I have created a shared component for action bar with different htms for android and ios and I use that on top of every other html

Comment: That would be perfect. Want I want to fully achieve is add and remove a navigation item, or load one actionbar, and then If I want a different one, load that one.

Comment: So got it working dynamically, just need to know how to load navigation items now

Answer (score 1):

`ActionBar` is applicable for `Page` inside a `Frame`. Use `actionBarHidden` property of `Page` to show / hide ActionBar. Use `actionItems` property of `ActionBar` to add action items.

Comment: I think Op's question was how to add actionbar dynamically using code not having that in html :)

Comment: Yeah, sorry for not being clear. Been going at this program for days.
Just want to do something like. page.addChild(Actionbar);

Comment: No, it doesn't work that way. It's always part of a page and you may decide to hide or show it with that property. Set items / navigation button dynamically if you wany to.

Answer (score 1):

```
var actionB = require("tns-core-modules/ui/action-bar).ActionBar;

var actB = new actionB();
actB.title = "Action Bar";
actB.id = "actionID"

var actionItemC = require("tns-core-modules/ui/action-bar).ActionItem;

var actItem = new actionItemC();
actB._addView(actItem)
```

and if you want to add navigation button

```
private getNavigationButton() {
    let navActionItem = new ActionItem();
    navActionItem.icon = 'res://ic_menu_white';
    if (navActionItem.ios) {
        navActionItem.ios.position = 'left';
    }
    navActionItem.on('tap', this.toggleDrawer.bind(this));
    return navActionItem;
}
```

and

```
if (isAndroid) {
        page.actionBar.navigationButton = this.getNavigationButton();
    }

    if (isIOS) {
        page.actionBar.actionItems.addItem(this.getNavigationButton());
    }
```

Comment: if you want to add NavigationButton than import it from same action bar module.
require("tns-core-modules/ui/action-bar).NavigationButton

Comment: I'm trying to add a NavigationButton:
var navB = new navButton();
navB.systemIcon = "ic_menu_btn_add":
actionB._addView(navB);

But I get nothing

Comment: When you debug can you see what is the icon asigned to navB?

Comment: when I console.log(navB.systemIcon); the Result is ic_menu_btn_add
Is that what you mean?

Comment: that is great, do you want to try actionB.content = navB; Or may add all navigationitems to a grid or stacklayout then add.

Comment: No luck, so close yet so far.
I think I have to do something with this "https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/modules/_ui_action_bar_"
I just don't understand enough

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182066/discussion-between-narendra-mongiya-and-thegoldend0nut).